# How to determine the logical converse of of a result

Tags: logic

I want to determine the logical converse of this result. I am confused.

The complex number $s=α+iβ$ is a solution of $f(s)=0$ and $α=1$ if and only if $g(s)≠0,h(s)=u(s)$ and $d(s)=v(s)$. Here the values of the mentioned functions are not important for the purpose of this function.

I know that if $a⇔b$, then converse of $a$⇔ converse of $b$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The converse is $f(s)\neq 0$ or $a\neq 1$ iff $g(s)=0$ or $h(s)\neq u(s)$ or $d(s)\neq v(s)$

This is because generally,
$$\neg \wedge\equiv \vee \neg$$
where $\neg$ is the negation, $\wedge$ is "and" $\vee$ is "or"

Indeed 
$$\neg (f(s)=0\wedge a=1)\equiv (\neg f(s) =0)\vee (\neg a=1)$$
and 
$$\neg (g(s)=0\wedge h(s)=u(s)\wedge d(s)=v(s))\equiv (\neg g(s) =0)\vee (\neg h(s)=u(s))\vee (\neg d(s)=v(s))$$

It might be useful to know that
$$\neg \forall\equiv \exists\neg$$
as well

Comment: Yes, but the case: $f(s)=0$ and $a≠1$ should be included.

Comment: @user53124 $A\vee B$ means "$A$" or "$B$" or "$A$ and $B$". That case is inculded in the "or"

Comment: Yes, and thank you. Things are now clear.